# eth_sendRawTransaction with DynamicFeeTx returns.. expected input list for types.LegacyTx

Tags: go-ethereum, rlp, eip-1559

I have composed an EIP-1559 DynamicFeeTx using golang.
`tx = types.NewTx(&types.DynamicFeeTx{Nonce: nonce, GasFeeCap: gasMax, GasTipCap: gasTip, Gas: gasLimit, To: &to, Value: value, Data: data})`
The exact code to generate the raw transaction is here https://go.dev/play/p/vk3GP_6j3FC
The raw tx generated hex data is the following:
`b87502f872038084e6a25bee85090257974c8255fc949c71fbe2d28080b8afa88cea8a1e319de2c09d448711c37937e0800080c001a02960b37d0e28c0c6995ebc64fde881a7427ff172fa0c53202e15186c2ab7a368a020f99445cfa033c6c16079e68d797096af60d226aaf2e69915d0fef01eeb8163`

When I submit the raw tx (using go or with https://ropsten.etherscan.io/pushTx) it returns..
`err:{"code":-32000,"message":"rlp: expected input list for types.LegacyTx"}`

I don't understand the error because it is a DynamicFeeTx and if I decode the raw tx the type is 2.

```
    var tx *types.Transaction
    rlp.DecodeBytes(raw, &tx)
    fmt.Printf("type:%v chainId:%v nonce:%d\n", tx.Type(), tx.ChainId(), tx.Nonce())
```

Where is the problem and what is the input list?

Answer (score 0):

I have investigated what is rlp, in this [link](https://eth.wiki/en/fundamentals/rlp) explains that is a serialization method and to encode a byte array of 117 bytes it ads a prefix 0xb875 (0x75=117) that is just the bytes at the beginning of the raw tx.

If I remove the first 2bytes (0xb875) of the raw tx when submitted to the rpc node the tx is broadcasted correctly.

```
err = node.Call("eth_sendRawTransaction", []interface{}{"0x" + hex.EncodeToString(raw[2:])}, &response)
```

In summary to decode the first 2bytes (0xb875) are necesary but to broadcast they should be removed.

Comment: Is there any explanation as to why broadcasting needs to be done without the first two bytes? Why doesn't geth handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Just follow this. It should work.

```
data, err := tx.MarshalBinary()
hexutil.Encode(data)
```

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: Basically the way how you convert the transacton to raw transaction is wrong.If you want to convert the EIP-1559 DynamicFeeTx to rawTransaction. You will have to marshal it and use the hexutil to encode it. so that it can be converted as hex string with 0x prefix.